# Getting this errors while importing

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products, duplicate, order-duplication

```
Duplicates found in column names: array ( 0 => 'sku', 1 => 'store_view_code', 2 => 'attribute_set_code', 3 => 'product_type', 4 => 'categories', 5 => 'product_websites', 6 => 'name', 7 => 'description', 8 => 'short_description', 9 => 'weight', 10 => 'product_online', 11 => 'tax_class_name', 12 => 'visibility', 13 => 'price', 14 => 'special_price', 15 => 'special_price_from_date', 16 => 'special_price_to_date', 17 => 'url_key', 18 => 'meta_title', 19 => 'meta_keywords', 20 => 'meta_description', 21 => 'base_image', 22 => 'base_image_label', 23 => 'small_image', 24 => 'small_image_label', 25 => 'thumbnail_image', 26 => 'thumbnail_image_label', 27 => 'swatch_image', 28 => 'swatch_image_label', 29 => 'created_at', 30 => 'updated_at', 31 => 'new_from_date', 32 => 'new_to_date', 33 => 'display_product_options_in', 34 => 'map_price', 35 => 'msrp_price', 36 => 'map_enabled', 37 => 'gift_message_available', 38 => 'custom_design', 39 => 'custom_design_from', 40 => 'custom_design_to', 41 => 'custom_layout_update', 42 => 'page_layout', 43 => 'product_options_container', 44 => 'msrp_display_actual_price_type', 45 => 'country_of_manufacture', 46 => 'additional_attributes', 47 => 'configurable_variations', 48 => 'configurable_variation_label', 49 => 'qty', 50 => 'out_of_stock_qty', 51 => 'use_config_min_qty', 52 => 'is_qty_decimal', 53 => 'allow_backorders', 54 => 'use_config_backorders', 55 => 'min_cart_qty', 56 => 'use_config_min_sale_qty', 57 => 'max_cart_qty', 58 => 'use_config_max_sale_qty', 59 => 'is_in_stock', 60 => 'notify_on_stock_below', 61 => 'use_config_notify_stock_qty', 62 => 'manage_stock', 63 => 'use_config_manage_stock', 64 => 'use_config_qty_increments', 65 => 'qty_increments', 66 => 'use_config_enable_qty_inc', 67 => 'enable_qty_increments', 68 => 'is_decimal_divided', 69 => 'website_id', 70 => 'related_skus', 71 => 'related_position', 72 => 'crosssell_skus', 73 => 'crosssell_position', 74 => 'upsell_skus', 75 => 'upsell_position', 76 => 'additional_images', 77 => 'additional_image_labels', 78 => 'hide_from_product_page', 79 => 'bundle_price_type', 80 => 'bundle_sku_type', 81 => 'bundle_price_view', 82 => 'bundle_weight_type', 83 => 'bundle_values', 84 => 'bundle_shipment_type', 85 => 'associated_skus', 86 => '', 87 => '', )
```

Comment: Try to export magento default change values as needed & then import

Comment: I did it but still receive the same error; does the duplicate means that the data is already there and can`t be processed??

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/134947)

Comment: I had the same issue, I just took my data and copied into a new blank spreadsheet with a different file name and voila. Not sure what's causing it, but that worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158381)

Answer (score 3):

Remove last two columns from your header. This error commonly come when Import CSV have duplicate entries in header.

Answer (score 1):

to import a csv file there cannot be empty columns, so you can delete empty columns in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue.  It turned out that a I had an extra column I forgot to delete.  I found this by doing the following.

1. Export either sample data or current products.
2. Copy the headers from this file.
3. Review the columns and make sure the header and columns still match correctly.

I've also seen some people be able to solve this by making sure their csv is UTF-8 encoded.